# Integration limits of the double integral after conversion to the polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I want to solve the following double integral:

$$\int_0^{\infty}dx\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dy\,f(x,y).$$

And for example I made a conversion to the polar coordinates, $x=r\cos{\theta}$ and $y=r\sin{\theta}$ and get a new integral where I plugged in new variables and multiplied the Integral with the Jacobian factor, in this case $r$. How could I find new integration limits in terms of $r$ and $\theta$ based on the integration limits in terms of $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$r:0 \to \infty
\\\theta : - \pi/2 \to \pi/2$$

Comment: thanks, Could you please explain how one can get those integration limits?

Comment: Your region is the right half plane. You have to cover it using the new limits.For $r$, think of a line starting from the origin and enters your region and leave it. For $\theta$, this line should rotate to cover the region, the angle $\theta$ measured with positive x-axis in positive direction

Comment: is this clear @user113891

Comment: thanks, I understood. The point is that has to be represented graphically, rather than that the integration limits has to be calculated by the lim, as I thought.

Comment: So, do you accept it. Any if you face any problem just  let me know

Comment: Sure! @semsem ....

Comment: Glad to help out